# Authorization WebAPI behaving like MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am using asp.core 2.1 to create web API's
I have a controller like this

```
 [Route("api")]
 [ApiController]
 public class LessonController : ControllerBase
 {

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("lessons/{id}")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Teacher")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetLesson(int id)
    {
      //....
    }
 }
```

With the `[Authorize]` attribute i just get the error below?

```
The default Identity UI layout requires a partial view '_LoginPartial' usually located at '/Pages/_LoginPartial' or....
```

As this is An API I'm confused as to why in the error it is looking for partial views?

Comment: Looks like you might be using `AddDefaultIdentity`, which configures ASP.NET Core Identity with the default UI, which is where this error ultimately comes from.

Comment: @Kirk spot on! add an answer and i'll mark as correct. Just had to change to       services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();....Thanks, just wasted a few hours on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you refer to comes from ASP.NET Core Identity's Default UI (specifically, it's in the `_Layout.cshtml` page [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.2/src/UI/Areas/Identity/Pages/V4/_Layout.cshtml#L42)). The Default UI is used when you use either of the following options in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<User, Role>()
    ...
```

-or-

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
    .AddDefaultUI()
    ...
```

If you don't want to use the Default UI, you'll need to avoid using `AddDefaultIdentity` and `AddDefaultUI` and just use `AddIdentity<User, Role>`.